# Debian 11 - Low entropy (256) even with Haveged and rng-tools on old laptop

Tags: debian, entropy-pool, random-number-generator

I have a problem with an old laptop.

I have installed a debian 11 operating system on it a year ago, and despite using it almost daily to perform network administration, I recently found its available entropy value is low, and don't seem to vary over time, or over activity.

```
# cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
256
```

I have **haveged** and **rng-tools** installed, with *HRNGDEVICE=/dev/urandom* as configuration for */etc/default/rng-tools-debian*.

Both rng-tools-debian and haveged services are running without errors.

My question is, how can I increase the entropy of my system ?

Thanks

System information:

- Laptop ref = Aspire V3-771G
- CPU = Intel Core i3-2328M
- Quantity of RAM = 6 Go
- Desktop = KDE Plasma
- No internet access, I manually enable internet access to apply security updates (1 time per week)
- I have installed haveged a while ago, rng-tools this morning, the entropy value didn't vary after the installation of rng-tools

EDIT:
I have a virtual machine (debian 11) running on a Windows 10 host (virtual box), with no desktop and no haveged, and I can see its entropy value going up quickly, reaching 1600+ in less than 1 minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found this : https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/v75t5w/entropy_of_devrandom_stuck_at_256/

But, my laptop is running kernel version 5.10.0-15-amd64.

Does anyone has an explanation ?

Thank you